# Lost responses from Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have updated my form with some responses recorded. After deleting one question section, the responses for that question disappeared. Can I still get to them?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Press **<kbd>`CTRL`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`LEFT ALT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`SHIFT`</kbd>** + **<kbd>`H`</kbd>** to invoke **Version history**:

[image: 0]